# Using Frobenius, show $y_1 = x$ of eqn $x^{3}y''-xy'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

My question is right at the beginning, I would like to use the indicial equation but solving for limits $p_0$ and $q_0$ for $r(r-1)+p_0r + q_0 = 0$, ie:

$p_0=\lim xp(x)$ for $x\rightarrow 0$  is $\infty$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may start by noticing that $y(x)=x$ is a solution of the given differential equation, and any solution of the given differential equation has to fulfill $y(0)=0$. By setting $y(x)=x\cdot f(x)$ the given DE boils down to:

$$ x^3 (2f'(x)+ x f''(x) )  - x (f(x)+ x f'(x)) + x f(x) = 0 $$
or:
$$ x^3 f''(x)   + (2x^2-  x)\,f'(x) = 0 $$
that is a separable DE for $f'$.
 It follows that the solutions to the original DE are given by $y(0)=0$ and
$$ y(x) = A x + B x e^{-1/x}\quad \text{for }x\neq 0. $$
If $B\neq 0$, there is an essential singularity at the origin, hence the Frobenius method is not well-suited for solving this problem. And actually, if $B\neq 0$, $y(x)$ is unbounded in a left neighbourhood of the origin.